# How to allow users over VPN to access Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-security

We have an Azure Web App and Azure VPN, we've locked down the web app so it's accessible internally only by granting/restricting access via IP addresses (via Access Restrictions page). However users over our VPN are not able to access the web app - when they connect over VPN, the user's external IP address is not from our internal network.  We do not want to whitelist everyone's IP address.

If we had the internal IP address of the web app, we have a few options we could try, but we assume this is not available to us.

How would we allow access to a web app for users over a VPN?
Is this something API Management would solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to whitelist everyone's IP address. You could involve front-ending the Web App with an [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) and restricting access to the Web App such that only connections from the Gateway are allowed.

Azure Application Gateway is a web traffic load balancer. It has a public or a private frontend or both backends, it must deploy in a dedicated subnet. The subnet also supports to restrict the network inbound and outbound traffic with NSG. In this case, you can deploy a private app GW, then the users over VPN will send the HTTP/HTTPS requests to the APP GW frontend, the APP GW receives the requests via Listener and routes the traffic to the appropriate backends based on the routing rules. An application gateway can communicate with to on-premises servers when they're connected by Azure ExpressRoute or VPN tunnels if traffic is allowed. See [supported backend pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pools) and [how an application gateway works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works).

You could get more references from the third way in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/02/15/web-app-with-vnet-only-access-using-app-gateway-powershell-automation/).